# Sobrecarga de operador ! con clase Visibility c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy intentando sobrecargar el operador unitario **!** en **C#**, para que reciba como parámetro un `Visibility`. Mi objetivo es que invierta la visibilidad de un controlador.

Ejemplo:

```
Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ControlName.Visivility = !ControlName.Visivility;
}
```

Para ello, he echo el siguiente código.

```
namespace Test
{
    //A namespace cannot directly contain a members such as fields or methods.
    public static Visibility operator !(Visibility visibility)
    {
        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible) return Visibility.Hidden;
        else return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    class VisivilityConverter
    {
        //The parameter of unary operator must be the containing type.
        public static Visibility operator !(Visibility visibility)
        {
            if (visibility == Visibility.Visible) return Visibility.Hidden;
            else return Visibility.Visible;
        }

    }
}
```

Pero resivo estos 2 errores:

- **Error 1:** A namespace cannot directly contain a
  members such as fields or methods.
- **Error 2:** The parameter of unary operator
  must be the containing type.

Si existe una forma de hacer esto, espero que alguien me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si, existe una forma de hacerlo y no es sobrecargando el operador !, si no haciendo un helper de transformacion (que es lo que usa wpf). si te interesa lo busco y pongo una respuesta

Comment: El objetivo es hacerlo en pocas lineas, y que se pueda llamar en cualquier parte del proyecto.

Comment: Igual el primer error es que pusiste una funcion fuera de una clase...

Comment: si se puede hacer con un trigger en wpf estaría bien.

Comment: No te va a servir lo que tengo, porque es un conversor de booleanos a visibilidad. Nunca tuve que cambiar la visibilidad de algo por codigo ya que para eso esta el viewmodel.. que estas tratando de conseguir? cambiar por codigo la visibilidad o en la ventana wpf?

Comment: Entre otras cosas, si quieres que tu sobrecarga de operador funcione, debes meter el operador de sobrecarga dentro de la clase `Visibility` si es tuya, de lo contrario, tendras que heredar o implementar dicha clase.

Comment: El problema es la clase `Visibility` es `sealed` no me deja heredarla.

Comment: Actualmente el código esta en un `click_event`

Comment: Como bien dices, al ser `Visibility` `sealed` no creo que sea posible lo que intentas. De todas maneras, tampoco veo necesario sobrecargar el operador, simplemente crea una clase `InvertirVisibility` o algo así y le pones el código que tienes ahora mismo.

Comment: Tienes razón eso es lo que voy ha hacer con una clase statica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La unica forma de sobreescribir los operadores es definiendolos en la clase misma y `Visibility` es un enum.

Lo que si puedes hacer es crear un metodo extensor que niegue el valor:

```
public static class VisibilityExtensions
{
   public static Visibility Negate(this Visibility v)
   {
     return v == Visibility.Visible ? Visiblity.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
   }
}
```

Uso:

```
Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ControlName.Visibility = ControlName.Visibility.Negate();
}
```

O puedes crear un metodo extensor que haga toggle a la propiedad `Visibility`. Si esta `Visible` lo cambia a `Hidden` y viceversa:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
   public class void ToggleVisibility(this Control control)
   {
      contro.Visibility = control.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
   }
}
```

Uso:

```
Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ControlName.ToggleVisibility();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Einer.

Answer (score 2):

Te comento, nunca vas a poder hacer sobrecarga de `Visibility`, ya que `Visibility` es un `enum`, y la sobrecargas de operadores aplica únicamente a `clases` y `struct`.

A lo sumo vas a poder crear una clase custom la cual te de dicha funcionalidad, pero lo que intentas hacer no es posible.

Comment: Ni con un UserControl?

Comment: La propiedad Visibility en si es un enum, de la misma no podrás hacer sobrecarga, podrías hacer un wrap con la misma en última instancia.